# NetSpeed gnome extension applet misbehaving on arch-linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome-shell

I have installed [NetSpeed](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/) extension on my arch-Linux. **It is working properly until I uninstalled [gnome-extra](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/gnome-extra/)** without affecting dependencies(-u --unneeded) package from my system. The problem is the visual bug that suddenly happened after that. **The netspeed icons next to speed turn to white boxes**. I checked the dependencies and packages under gnome-extra. And there's no appropriate package I could found there. I tried uninstalling and installing NetSpeed extension, but no use. I donot want to install full set of programs in gnome-extra again.

Before:
 [image]

After:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer myself. Weirdly, the problem was with the package called gnome-builder inside the bundled [gnome-extra](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/gnome-extra/).
Reinstalling **[gnome-builder](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gnome-builder/)** with `sudo pacman -S gnome-builder` would solve the problem.